# Custom timeframe date range in azure workbooks as json body

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

Unable to pass custom timeframe date range from json body using azure resource manager data source

this is the way I have tried to get cost details using time range, it works if I pass static values, but fails if it passed from a parameter.

[image: 1]

Comment: having a concrete example of exactly the json body that works, and exactly the json body that workbooks generates (you could get from F12 network tools) would really help here.

Answer (score 0):

in the screenshot, you have `timeperiod` with a lower case p, but in the cost management [API docs for /query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage?tabs=HTTP#request-body) it shows it being `timePeriod` with a capital P.  its strange that the docs don't explicitly state what the *format* of the string should be?

by default workbooks would format that as JSON dates, but you might need to use `{TimeRange:startISO}` or `{TimeRange:startUnix} or something if it is expecting some other format?